# Cannot start workstation service on DC

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I followed [this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows) to disable SMBv1 server and client with Group Policy. After that, my DC seems down as I got many error that no AC server is founded in my domain. I then found the workstation service cannot be started, it said "Windows could not start the Worksation service on Local Computer. Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified".

The registry I changed are here:

https://msegceporticoprodassets.blob.core.windows.net/asset-blobs/4023804_en_2

However, even I deleted these new created registry keys, I still cannot get my DC back. This is the only DC in my environment. Help!!

Comment: So, you broke your only domain controller... I would advise finding a consultant and being prepared to pay to untangle this mess.  While you're at it, it would probably be worthwhile to see about getting a secondary DC setup and doing backups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved it myself. Not sure why, but i ran the command

***sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend=bowser/mrxsmb10/mrxsmb20/nsi***

and

***sc.exe config mrxsmb10 start=disabled***

Reboot the server; then run

***sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend=bowser/mrxsmb20/nsi***

After reboot the server again, now I can start the workstation service and other services now. my DC is back!